# Publish an ExtJS 5 Application in a subdirectory

Tags: .net, extjs, extjs5

I'm trying to put my ExtJS 5 application which created at Sencha Architect inside Scripts directory of a .Net MVC 4 application.

I put all my ExtJS project under /Scripts/my_extjs_app directory and created a bundle like below.

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/extjs").Include(
        "~/Scripts/my_extjs_app/bootstrap.js"));
```

The thing is, when bootstrap.js runs, its trying to load:

```
    http://localhost:5555/app.js?_dc=1417004731147
```

istead of:

```
    http://localhost:5555/Scripts/my_extjs_app/app.js?_dc=1417004731147
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you open up app.json then you can edit "indexHtmlPath" that lets you specify a path to your application's index page. Either that or the "url" property should do what you want, though you'll likely need to do `sencha app build` to refresh the bootstrap files.